# Can a function be used to approximate a matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

I am interested to know class of functions that can be used to approximate large matrices. The reason of this is dimensionality reduction, so if we will have to use Taylor series approximation methods then we fall into the same curse of dimensionality situation. So are there any class of function that are compact in a sense that they are quite versatile and can mimick any matrices just by changing few parameters, maybe the order of parameters can add versatility.

Comment: Do you want approximation or exact containing?

Comment: @EDX not exact but a replacement. So instead of writing data in a matrix form where matrix basically represents correlation/connection between dimensions, I want to have it represent in a functional form which is also compact. So a functional form shouldnt be in a similar dimension as the matrix because that will not justify the use of functional form if we have to have same number of functions or  terms in the series as the amount of dimentions in the matrix form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use Lagrange interpolation setting the $x_i$ of Lagrange interpolation as the first $n^2$ whole number. So

$$L(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}a_i\prod_{j\neq i}\left(\dfrac{X-i}{i-j}\right)$$
And
$$\forall k\leq n^2 f(k) \simeq a_k $$

If sufficient to describe your matrix

---

One of an approach in terms of approximation of your matrix is to use the of **Piantadosi function**. **The advantage of that method is that, even if it is approximation (in fact very thin approximation), it provides a certain regularity between the approximated values where Lagrange does not**

---

Let $A$ in $ M_n(\mathbb{R})$:

$$A=(a_{i,j})=({a_k})_{k\in[1,n^2]}$$

---

Let define the matrix $A'$ as the reduced matrix in sort of the coefficent of $A'$ are all inferior to 1

$$A'=\max(c,10^{-c}|a_k|<1, k\leq n^2)\times A$$

---

Now define the **Piantadosi function** associated to $A'$
$$f_{k, p} (x) = \sin^2(2^{kx}\arcsin(p))$$

---

Where $k$ is a natural number (the **precision**)
And $p$ is the number binary constructed by the concatenations of the $k$ first digits of each of the $n^2$ coefficients of your matrix.

**So all you matrix is in** $f$.

Example :

With the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0.4 & 0.2\\
0.5 & 0.25 \end{pmatrix}$$

$a_1=0.0110011..., a_2=0.0011001100..., a_3=0.1,a_4=0.01$ in binary.

So if we choose $k=5$ we take the first five digit of each $a_k$ and put one after other to construct $p$

Concretely $p=0.01100001101000001000$ in binary.

And we have the fundamental relation : $$\forall k\leq n^2 f(k) \simeq a_k $$

For further explaination on Piantadosi function see :

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjlt634g5PrAhVH3IUKHZB-BI8QFjADegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfs.semanticscholar.org%2F9f4a%2F4d01294fd1fcc3f80a3a7c876055971b7663.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2H8MGA2h9mIyse

Comment: the link is broken and latex isnt rendered well. So I like the fact your mentioned coefficient reduction with the norm of $a_i$, I think this is the answer I am looking for. Can you please elaborate the coefficient reduction part?  $p$ is the parameters right?

Comment: I add some precision !

Comment: noted. It is the answer I was looking for. Good job.

Comment: Thanks ! Note that this function is much more powerful than a simple Lagrange interpolation that could have also done the job, because Lagrange interpolation functions are too oscillating functions. What ever the number of your coefficient is, it will fit, even between the values ! That caracteristic is called **universal** caracter ( Zeta has it so for holomorphic function)

Comment: Noted. It is powerfull because Piantadosi function can fit any number of coefficients but Lagrange interpolation cannot fit any number of coefficients right?

Comment: Not exactly, Lagrange interpolation can fit a finite number of coefficient **exactly**. Piantadosi do an approximation job (ultra-precise). Yet, if you want to get approximation than includes good fitting between the values of your parameter you should use Piantadosi. I going to addLagrange option.

Comment: Perfect. You really gave a holistic overview.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform to Fourier series and find the principal frequencies to help determine the major frequencies that contribute to most information in the matrix. But then you will loose some information. Ideally there are no class of functions that can achieve this with few parameters without loosing information.

Comment: Fine, I am aware fourier series are used in data compression, my aim is not compression but lossless representation of same information but instead of matrix, in the form of compact analytical functions.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER If you really want *exact* representation, unless there is a nice "banding structure" to exploit (like, for example, the discretized Laplacian on a square grid), about all there is to do is a sparse matrix representation.

Comment: @Ian, could you please elaborate. I couldnt get much info on "banding structure" by google search apart from physics. Are you saying if we want exact representation, only sparse matrix representation is the recommended choice?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER If there is some nice pattern in the coefficients, then you can take advantage of that to get an algorithmic representation of the corresponding linear operator without storing an actual array of coefficients. Otherwise there is not much better than just a sparse matrix representation, at least among exact (or rather exact modulo arithmetic error) representations of the corresponding operator.

Comment: @Ian, Your comment makes lots of sense. This "nice pattern" is what most Machine Learning algorithms tend to exploit right?

Comment: Just keep in mind there is not much to be done for lossless representation. If there is a pattern then you can surely use machine learning algorithms